# Sencha Touch theming: custom back button

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sass

I'm trying to declare a series of back button.

My goal is to do 
ui: 'back-black'
ui: 'back-red'
ui: 'back-green'

and it changes the style **but it keeps the arrow shape**

so far I've only managed to change all the ui:'back' buttons

```
 .x-button-back, .x-button-back:after  { 
  background:#ff0000 none !important;
}
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try `ui:'normal-black'` or `ui:'round-black'`?

**UPDATE**

For that you need to edit your project's Sass files. Add this line to the scss file for each color you want

```
@include sencha-button-ui('orange',#ff8000,'glossy');
```

and similar

```
@include sencha-button-ui('red',#ff0000,'matte');
```

Check this videos for more info:

http://vimeo.com/33298159 (the example is at 17:00)

http://vimeo.com/17879651

http://www.sencha.com/learn/theming-sencha-frameworks-with-sass-and-compass/

And the CSS3 cheat sheet 
http://downloads.sencha.com/extras/css3-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: what I want is to be able to change the color ui:back which is a button shaped like an arrow.I can change the color of ui:back but only once. what I want is to keep the arrow shape and define several colors

Answer (score 4):

On the card:

```
config: {

    defaultBackButtonText: '',
    navigationBar: {
        backButton: {
            iconCls: 'back',
            ui: 'plain'
        }
    }
}
```

On the CSS:

```
//Back
.x-button-icon.back {
background-image: url(../../resources/images/bt_seta.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The chosen answer is probably wrong or does not applicable to Sencha 2.0.1. I tried the anwer but it doesn't work in Sencha Touch 2.0.1. However, the following method works:

1. (Optional) Import your favourite color via sass in your sass:

   ```
   @include sencha-button-ui('orange',#ff8000,'glossy');
   ```
2. Put it in ui like

   ```
   ui: "orange-back"
   ```

   or

   ```
   ui: "red-back"
   ```

... etc.

Comment: thanks for the update, I asked this question end of 2011 when ST2 was in the infancy of beta testing so my project was in ST1^^

Comment: No problem. I faced the same issue and searched through. This thing doesn't work in ST2! That's why I offered this answer in case anyone needed it ;)